# Объясните смысл данного кода

Tags: c, инспекция-кода

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    //string key = argv[1]
    if (argc !=2)
    {
        printf("Please, enter a normal key");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        int k = atoi(argv[1]) % 26;
        if(k == 0)
        {
            printf("It is a wrong key. Try one more time");
            return 1;
        }

        string word = GetString();
        if(word != NULL);
        {
            for (int i = 0, n = strlen(word); i < n; i++)
            {
                int c = 0;
                if(isupper(word[i]))
                {
                    c = (((int)word[i] - 65 + k) % 26) + 65;
                    printf("%c", (char)c);
                }
                else if(islower(word[i]))
                {
                    c = (((int)word[i] - 97 + k) % 26) + 97;
                    printf("%c", (char)c);
                }
                else 
                    printf("%c", word[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
c = (((int)word[i] - 65 + k) % 26) + 65;

c = (((int)word[i] - 97 + k) %26) + 97;
```

Answer (score 5):

Некрасивый код. Сначала заметим что `A` = 65 и `a` = 97, число символов в алфавите = 26.

Перепишем `c = (((int)word[i] + k -'A') % ALPHABET_SIZE) + 'A'`

Уже чуть понятнее, это шифр Цезаря, циклическая сдвиг алфавита на несколько символов вправо.

1 строка - большие буквы, 2 - маленькие.

Например при k = 3 мы заменим `a->d b->e ... x->a y->b z->c`

Comment: Тут ещё и утечка памяти есть - не освобождается буфер выделенный под строку `word`.

Comment: Только *alphabet* лучше звучит.